On premise Kubeadm Setup
I am a newbie to Kubernetes. I am learning to set up an on-premise Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm. I have referred to the k8s documentation, and it seems to be tricky, as I am not getting the desired results. I want your guidance for the same
Note : I have 3 laptops. I want to make 1 laptop as master and other 2 as worker node.
I am facing issues in networking. The permission to ports are denied. Also, I am not sure about the KubernetesCOnfig file and the cgroup drivers.
abhijithmallya@abhijithmallya-ROG-Strix-G512LI-G512LI:~$ sudo kubeadm init
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.30.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING Swap]: swap is supported for cgroup v2 only; the NodeSwap feature gate of the kubelet is beta but disabled by default
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
W0721 12:19:30.746701   25206 checks.go:844] detected that the sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8" of the container runtime is inconsistent with that used by kubeadm.It is recommended to use "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9" as the CRI sandbox image.
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [abhijithmallya-rog-strix-g512li-g512li kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 192.168.1.11]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [abhijithmallya-rog-strix-g512li-g512li localhost] and IPs [192.168.1.11 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [abhijithmallya-rog-strix-g512li-g512li localhost] and IPs [192.168.1.11 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "super-admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[kubelet-check] Waiting for a healthy kubelet. This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] The kubelet is not healthy after 4m0.001055738s

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://127.0.0.1:10248/healthz' returned error: Get "http://127.0.0.1:10248/healthz": context deadline exceeded


This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: could not initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

Also, port are not accessible
abhijithmallya@abhijithmallya-ROG-Strix-G512LI-G512LI:~$ nc 127.0.0.1 6443 -v
nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

I actually have a docker compose file of my project. I want to deploy that into the kubeadm cluster. I am just 1 week old into k8s. So please guide me
I tried using the Steps in the k8s documentation. But I am unable to get the results as shown there. There are no clear troubleshooting for my errors.
